# how to concatenate bits in javascript?

Tags: javascript, casting, binary

I want to concatenate the bits of two number values like this:

```
+---------+---------+---------+-----------------+
|         |  val1   |  val2   | concatenate val |
+---------+---------+---------+-----------------+
| decimal | 18      | 16      | 592             |
| hexa    | 0x12    | 0x10    | 0x250           |
| binary  | 0b10010 | 0b10000 | 0b1001010000    |
+---------+---------+---------+-----------------+
```

I have try to just concatenate with + like that :

```js
const test = 0b10010, test1 = 0b10000
console.log(test+test1)//return 34
```

It does not concatenate the values but adds them together.

Comment: `parseInt(test.toString(2) + test1.toString(2), 2)`

Comment: It works also but it's weird to cast number into a string to concatenate

Comment: What exactly is this supposed to do? "Concatenating" binary numbers like this is *unusual*, because internally they are stored as 32bit ints. So `0b10010` is actually `0b00000000000000000000000000010010`

Comment: I try to speak with socket protocol and I store the byte that I receive into an Uinit8Array but in the protocol frame there is a mac address that is encoded in 6bytes and to store this address I need to concatenate some byte of the frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could shift the first value by the bitwise length of the second value before adding.

```js
const
    add = (a, b) => (a << Math.ceil(Math.log2(b)) + 1) + b;
    test = 0b10010,
    test1 = 0b10000,

console.log(add(test, test1)); //
```

Comment: It totally works but what this function is doing? What is << and math.log2() ?

Comment: @MrSolarius “<<“ is the left shift operator https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Left_shift

Comment: Thanks for your response and information ^^

Comment: @MrSolarius Rather than `Math.ceil(Math.log2(b)) + 1` you can use the simpler `32-Math.clz32(b)`...